# understanding software architecture of groovy in createCriteria().list closure of Gorm API

Tags: grails, groovy, closures, dsl

Most of the time,  when developing `groovy` closures, the defined parameters are : `it` or another parameters written at calls .
i.e :

```
   //example when using it 
  list.grep{it % 2 ==0}
```

or :

```
 // example when using parameters (e)
 list.grep{e->e % 2 ==0}
```

The thing that i don't understand the following :

```
  MyDomain.createCriteria().list{
       eq('name',name);
       order('dateCreated');

  }
```

What's the software architecture to interpret many calls **together** in one closure.

Should closure extends a class that implements : `eq` , `order`,`max` .. methods . If yes , How is it declared ?

After inspecting Gorm  , i reach to the following result : `createCriteria` can be applied to class that extends `GormInstanceApi`.

However , the issue have been ambiguous yet.

Comment: You can set the delegate of closures in groovy http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2009/11/groovy-goodness-setting-closures.html

Comment: very useful . def thanks={println 'Thank u $name .'} ; thanks.delegate=new Person(name:'tim_yates')

Comment: What version of Grails?